# Google Chrome blocks new links to be opened in new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, popup, popupwindow

Anyone else have noticed this behaviour in Google Chrome.

Some of the links on website try to open as popup window and get blocked by chrome popup blocker.

On ES website, partner slots occasionally work as intended (i.e by opening the page in new tab once clicked) but most of the time they just get blocked.

I am attaching a screenshot for better clarity and understanding. Please reply If you have any inputs.

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior but colleagues of mine are not (or at least haven't noticed it). Investigating and will follow-up if I come up with anything.

Comment: Submitted a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=1&q=pop%20up%20tab%20block&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&sort=-modified&id=305351&thanks=305351&ts=1381261998) to Chromium.